# GFCI trips after 18-20 min of treadmill use

Tags: gfci

I had a new GFCI outlet added on a 3 yr old house that had zero issues.  While they were installing there was a flash of light at the main panel.  They told me the light was an arc and not a problem. The new gfci outlet trips after me using the treadmill 18-20min.  My original outlet in the basement has no issues with me running the treadmill 50+ minutes.  I also have my microwave tripping out randomly when I use it.  Never had the issue prior to the new outlet being put in.  Could the arc have caused damage?  Any ideas why the new gfci outlets trips after 18-20 min and why my microwave trips since the new GFCI outlet was add(add the arc happened at the main panel)?

Comment: Was the treadmill plugged in to a non-GFCI outlet until you installed this new one?

Comment: It's possible that the motor in your treadmill is not compatible with a GFCI outlet and needs a circuit not protected by one.  It's likely that the arc flash while the electricians were working is of no lasting relevance.

Comment: When the microwave is "tripping out", is that a local GFCI trip, the treadmill GFCI trip, or microwave "regular breaker" trip? Picture of the panel with circuits identified may help.

Comment: Also, an arc does not necessarily have any lasting damage. But an arc when working on ordinary breakers should be a very rare event. So that makes me wonder a bit about the qualifications of the electrician...

Comment: Could the arc have caused damage - yes. Enough so that it intermittently trips a GFCI (running microwaves and motors) - probably not. - welcome to GFCIs and *nuisance trips*. - It's possible that it only needs to be an AFCI, which afaik nuisance trip less often.